# Working with GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

is there a way to add groups to GridView in xaml like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridView" SelectionMode="None">
        <GroupItem x:Name="Group1">

        </GroupItem>
    </GridView>
```

And add items like this:

```
Group1.Items.Add(UIElement)?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple StackPanels in grid.

```
 <GridView x:Name="GridView" SelectionMode="None">
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Name="sc" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Start Time : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookedFromDteTme }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Finish Time: " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookedToDteTme }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Task Address : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskAddress}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel></GridView>
```

and then add controls dynamically

```
 Button btn = new Button() { Content = "Button" };
            btn.Width=130;
            btn.Height = 66;
  sc.Children.Add(btn);
```